# Listing AD Attributes with powershell using DirectoryServices on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

I am trying to get a list of user names and their pwdlastset attribute on a Windows Server 2008 DC. I am using directoryservices because there are no adutils installed. The script is working, but I am inexperienced with powershell and would like to know how to improve the output formatting. Currently, user Names and Dates are printed each in a new line. I get something like this:

> user1
>
> pwdlastsetdate
>
> user2
>
> pwdlastsetdate

How can I get something like

> user1;pwdlastsetdate
>
> user2;pwdlastsetdate

Thank you!

This is the script I am using:

```
$SR=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://OU=OrganisationName,OU=Users,DC=site,DC=orgname,DC=de")
$searcher=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($SR)
$searcher.Filter="(&(objectCategory=User))"
$results=$searcher.findall()
foreach ($usr in $results)
{
    $usrdata = $usr.Properties
    $usrdata.name
    [DateTime]::FromFileTime($usrdata.pwdlastset[0]).ToString("d")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom array, by doing something like this:

```
$SR=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://OU=OrganisationName,OU=Users,DC=site,DC=orgname,DC=de")
$searcher=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($SR)
$searcher.Filter="(&(objectCategory=User))"
$results=$searcher.findall()

$allinfo = @()

foreach ($usr in $results)
{
    $info = "" | Select Name,Date
    $usrdata = $usr.Properties

    #Without [0] you get curly brackets in username output

    $info.Name = $usrdata.name[0]
    $info.Date = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($usrdata.pwdlastset[0]).ToString("d")
    $allinfo += $info
}
```

Now you have an array with the information which you could simply print or format using format-table

```
$allinfo

$allinfo | format-table

$allinfo | export-csv -NoTypeInformation c:\allinfo.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! The format is just like what I was aiming for. With your solution, the usernames were in curly brackets. I edited the line $info.Name = $usrdata.name to $info.name = usrdata.name[0] and the brackets were gone.

Comment: Glad to hear, please mark the answer as your solution.

Comment: Please don't teach users using the `+=` operator on arrays as it's [_very expensive_ operation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster/).  Capture all the output of the loop instead as `$allinfo = foreach ($usr in $results) { $usrdata = $usr.Properties; [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = $usrdata.Name; Date = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($usrdata.pwdlastset[0]).ToString("d") } }`. _Just make sure the loop only outputs the raw data you want in the report._